# Compiled Access Program Runs Fine on 7 Computers but Crashes on 3 others

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a rather complex application in Microsoft Access. It is split into front end and back end files. To protect my code, I have compiled it and saved it as a runtime .accde file, which I then changed to an .accdr file to ensure it operated as a runtime. I have created two versions of the application: one for those with 32-bit Office installed and one for those with 64-bit office. I have used Inno Setup to package the application, the data file, and other files such as the icon file, the license file, etc., into an installable package, which works just fine.

Among my team of 27 beta testers of this application, so far 6 have downloaded it, and I have tested it on four of my own computers. On seven of these computers, the installation works perfectly and the application runs with no problems.

On the computers of three of my testers, when they try to run it, they get this error message:

```
The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Bad file name or number.
 * The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
```

I'm pretty sure I know where the code is that's causing the problem, but cannot for the life of me figure out why the application crashes on those 2 computers but not on others.

The On Open event I suspect of causing the problem checks the linked tables, gets their connect string, then looks at the path for that string for the back end database. If it does not find it there, the procedure pops up a file selector dialog and instructs the user to find the data file, then it relinks all the tables.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to fixing this problem, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem?  Tell me more about the successful/failing environments. Show me the failing code. Or should I just guess.

Comment: Thanks, donPablo, but I myself am guessing at the failing code at the moment, because it runs perfectly on all 4 of my own machines, and I cannot recreate the error. The testers have varied environments, both 32-bit and 64-bit Office installed, and no office installed but using the Access runtime. I can find no consistency of environment among the computers that crash. I suspect it may have to do with the auto-relinking of linked tables feature, and that's what I've spent several hours on this morning, totally rewriting and meticulously testing that routine.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by a reference labelled as MISSING.

You have two (three) options:

1. Run the application on the offending machines with a full version of Access that lets you debug the code
2. Create a small test application that lists and verifies the references you use, and run this on the offending machines
3. Remove those two customers

Comment: Thanks for this, but you cannot debug compiled Access programs even with a full version of Access; and I am not willing to send my uncompiled code "into the wild."

Comment: Then remove those two wild users. See edited answer, please.

Comment: However, I am rewriting the code for the auto-relink feature, as I suspect this is where the fault lies. After I test the fool out of this new code, I'll send it to those who had it crash before, and we'll see if I was right. My latest theory is that it crashed because of an untrapped error that only occurs in specific circumstances when trying to relink to the back end DB, maybe because the BEDB is in an unexpected location.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the contributors here. Because of these folks and additional online research, the latest answer I can find is this:

This error occurs on a small percentage of computers on which the app is installed, and **no one has yet figured out why, what causes it, or how to fix it.** The workaround is to install the 2013 version of the Access runtime, as later versions will still cause the problem.

At least one of the offending computers is running the Click-to-Run version of Office. Still gathering information, but that's the status as of now.

Comment: Can you provide references, where you got these informations from? And a hint from my side: Try to compile with the oldest Access version (in your case 2013 **RTM**). Compiling with an Access version which already contains patches can cause trouble on clients having non- (or older) patched Access running.

Comment: To Unhandled Exception - I would love to provide references, but I am plowing through so many articles and emails and postings and other references so fast, I just don't have time to track who said what where. Thanks for these inputs, and I'll have to see if I can somehow get a copy of Access 2013. This might take some maneuvering, since MS seems to want to always update me to the latest version with or without my okay. But meantime, I'll also have the users whose computers are throwing those errors try the Access 2013 runtime and see what happens. Yep, it's a mess, all right.